# Getting Concurrency Issue in data in MapState in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have used MapState in my flink jobs, but sometimes i have noticed that data is jumbled in different keys in MapState for a momentary time. Is there any existimg concurrency issue with MapState?

Declaration-

```java
private transient MapState<String, Map<String, Double>> mapState = null;
```

Usage-

within processElement function.

```java
Map<String, Double> KPIData;
Double currentValue;
Double previousValue = null;

if (mapState.contains(mapKey)) {
    KPIData = mapState.get(mapKey);
    if (KPIData.containsKey(userRoleId)) {
        previousValue = KPIData.get(userRoleId);
        currentValue = CalculatorService.fetchValue(KPIData.get(userRoleId), newEquation, recordAsMap);
    } else {
        currentValue = calculateDefaultValue(recordAsMap, newEquation);
    }
} else {
    KPIData = new HashMap<>();
    currentValue = calculateDefaultValue(recordAsMap, newEquation);
}

if (null != currentValue) {
     KPIData.put(userRoleId, currentValue);
}
```

Comment: Where does `mapKey` come from?

Comment: And where do you call `mapState.put(KPIData)`, after you've had to create `KPIData` because it doesn't exist in `mapState`?